# how to substitute all the occurrences of a pattern in a word list in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

In Makefile's `$(patsubst pattern, replacement, text)` statment, it searches for any `pattern` in the white space separated word list of `text` and replaces them with replacement. But the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) says

```
Only the first ‘%’ in the pattern and replacement is treated this way; any subsequent ‘%’ is unchanged.
```

Suppose I have
`test_list := test1 test2`
and I want to make a list `build/test1/test1 build/test2/test2` from it.  Because patsubst substitutes only the first occurrence, if I do `$(patsubst %, build/%/%, $(test_list))`, it gives me `build/test1/% build/test2/%`. How can I make `build/test1/test1 build/test2/test2`? Is there variant of patsubst which converts all the occurrences?

Comment: For advanced `make` programming you may want to look at the GNUmake library [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which has a number of text manipulation functions - some of them only documented in the source - sorry, need to find time to polish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this rather simple case `foreach` should do what you want:

```
$(foreach t,$(test_list),build/$(t)/$(t))
```

Comment: Thanks! so I did `del_list := $(foreach t, $(test_list), build/$(t)/$(t))` and in the clean rule, `rm -f $(del_list)`.